# Does MS Edge support multi-account containers across tabs?

Tags: microsoft-edge, cookies, session

My company's web app maintains sessions via cookies. One of our customers uses `MS Edge` and wants to be able to have a completely separate session running our web app in each browser tab, for sometimes 2 but up to 3 tabs and 3 separate sessions.

Getting 2 different sessions is pretty easy by using 1 normal Edge window + 1 private/incognito window. The 2 sessions are separate and that's what they want. But what if they want 3 tabs and 3 sessions? My understanding is that when you're in the private/incognito space, ALL private/incognito tabs will share the same cookies and thus the same session. Is my understanding correct? And if so, is there any way to force different cookies (and thus different sessions) on a per-tab basis in Edge?

Apparently Firefox has a way to achieve this ([Firefox Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/)) so I'm wondering if Edge may have something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Microsoft Edge has no container support like Firefox.

Comment: Any way to simulate such behavior? Like forcing each private tab to not share cookies with other tabs?

Answer (score 1):

you can create multiple profiles, each profile has their own cookies, but in different windows.

you can read the following articles:

1. [Open a "new session" in Edge](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/open-a-new-session-in-edge/4f1f56ff-54ce-405e-808b-8c6131afa69a)
2. [Sign in and create multiple profiles in Microsoft Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/sign-in-and-create-multiple-profiles-in-microsoft-edge-df94e622-2061-49ae-ad1d-6f0e43ce6435)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1171558)

Comment: @help-info.de Thank you for your correction, I'm a novice and my English is not good, the first sentence of my answer already contains the answer, the two linked articles below provide more detailed instructions.

Comment: Brevivity is OK but fuller explanations are better. See [answer]